# GREP equivalent for Windows OS through Python script

Tags: python-3.x, windows, batch-file, cmd, grep

Please, can someone help me with an alternative for Windows to the following command:

**Linux Version:**
find Win32_EXE -type f -name '*.json' -exec grep --files-with-match -i 'dbtool' '{}' ;

**Windows version:**
FIND /i "dbtool" \Win32_EXE*.json

***Problem**: The windows syntax lacks an option letting me specify that I want a result returned on the first match.*

Comment: Does it have to be Python, or can you use powershell?

Comment: For this case, it must be such that it gets run through a python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python I would use a recursive glob:

```
from glob import iglob

def search(file):
    with open(file) as fo:
        for line in fo:
            if "dbtool" in line.lower():
                return True
    return False

for file in iglob("Win32_EXE/**/*.json", recursive=True):
    if search(file):
        print(file)
```

but I think in general I wouldn't use Python - other solutions are probably faster/better.
e.g. Powershell

```
get-childitem -recurse *.json | where-object { select-string -quiet -pattern "dbtool" -path $_ }
```

or, if you can install [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), that works well.

```
rg -l -g "*.json" -i dbtool Win32_EXE
```

Answer (score 0):

This will search for *.json files and search them for the string `dbtool`. Change the PUSHD directory to your search directory.

```
PUSHD "C:\src\t"
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /S /B /A:-D "*.json"') DO (
    FIND /I "dbtool" "%%~A"
)
POPD
```